# Locking User account created under Windows Authentication in SQL Server

Tags: sql, locking

As per my project requirement i need to lock a user in SQL Server(Which is created using Windows Authentication). Is there any way to do this?

For example: For a SQL login if you try to login using wrong Password more than 3 or 4 attempts, then that account gets locked out. User cannot login to SQL Server using this username. I want to check this using Users created under windows authenntication

Thanks for the help

Santhosh

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep two things apart:

- on a **server-level**, you have users that have a **login** - this gives them the ability to connect to that SQL Server at all. You can disable a login using:

  ```
  ALTER LOGIN (name) DISABLE
  ```

  Doing so prevents that user from logging into the database server alltogether - he (or she) cannot access anything on that database server anymore
- on a **per-database level**, those logins might be granted access to the database - this is done by creating a **user** (based on that login) for that database, and assigning that user certain permissions. You can't really disable a user in a database - you just have to drop that user

  ```
  USE (database)
  DROP USER (name)
  ```

  You can always re-create that user from his login in that database using

  ```
  USE (database)
  CREATE USER (name) WITH LOGIN = (login name)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..
I am not talking about Disabling a user!!!, I want to lock an account!! For example if you consider a SQL user, after 3 or 4 login counts account gets locked. I want to check whether this is possible with users created using Windows Auhtentication!

Comment: I can lock the AD account directly. When i try to add this locked AD account into SQL Server, that account in SQL Server is unlocked. I want to Lock this user in SQL Server also

Comment: Then see above - you can either DISABLE the entire login for the user, or you need to DROP the user in the given database. I don't see any other options, really.