# Lock SQL login programmatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to programmatically lock a SQL-Server login. The goal is to emulate the automatic function in SQL that will lock out a user that makes several connection attempts with a bad password.

I can easily unlock a login, but I need to lock it as well.

I have tried looping through 20 times with a .NET `sqlConnection` that contained an invalid password and I get very inconsistent results.

Comment: You can disable a login using `ALTER LOGIN username DISABLE`. Actual lock seems to be impossible to do programmatically, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605814/locking-user-account-created-under-windows-authentication-in-sql-server

Comment: What's the distinction between a locked account and a disabled account?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `SqlConnetion` client:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER LOGIN [Username] DISABLE", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Alternatively you could deny the user the permission to connect (as long as the user is not a member of the `sysadmin` role).  Note that in order to do this, you must connect to the `master` database since it is a server-level permission:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionStringToMasterDatabase))
{
    con.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("DENY CONNECT SQL TO [Username]", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately neither of these seems to lock the account.

What is troubling to me is that I can't seem to simulate invalid login attempts to cause the lock to occur.  

    ~Do Until number > 20
            number += 1
            NewSqlConn = Nothing
            NewSqlConn = New SqlConnection
            NewSqlConn.ConnectionString = sbConnString.ToString()
            NewSqlConn = New SqlConnection
            Try
                NewSqlConn.Open()
            Catch
            End Try
    Loop~

Comment: Are you sure the login you are trying to lock is an actual SQL Server login (not just a user stored in the database and maintained by the application)?

Comment: Yes, I created the database and the login.